# Deploy Mercurial master branch to Heroku

Tags: heroku, mercurial, hg-git

I've been deploying my hg repo to Heroku using hg-git for a few months, but it's stopped working recently.

```
0 HAL:0 work/nrb % hg push git+ssh://git@heroku.com:nrb.git
pushing to git+ssh://git@heroku.com:nrb.git/
exporting hg objects to git
converting revision 75ef42d9fe22b99259a2a05b28be56c92d0aa01b
creating and sending data
["git-receive-pack 'nrb.git'"]
Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build.
```

As you can see Heroku wants a master branch. I tried creating one and pushing with

`hg push -b master git+ssh://git@heroku.com:nrb.git/`

but got the same result. **Is there a way to get hg-git to push a branch named master to Heroku?**

Comment: Try replacing the "-b" in your command with "-B".  Lowercase means to push a branch, while uppercase means to push a bookmark, which is what Hg-Git maps to Git branches (in the most common use-cases, anyway).  It might be helpful to include some information about your repository, in particular what bookmarks exist.

Comment: That was it, thanks. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the "-b" in your command with "-B". Lowercase means to push a branch, while uppercase means to push a bookmark, which is what Hg-Git maps to Git branches (in the most common use-cases, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check content of `.hg\git\HEAD` file, it must be `ref: refs/heads/master`
2. Verify and fix if needed data of tip

   `$ hg log -r tip`

   `changeset:   7:32bbc6bc3867`

   `bookmark:    master`

   `tag:         default/master`

   `tag:         tip`